# Android Picaso - How to not cache images that are not downloaded through it?

Tags: java, android, image, caching, picasso

So I am using Picaso to load some images and cache them like so:

```
    ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_logo);
    Picasso.with(VenueDetailsActivity.this).load(url).into(logo);
```

However, I have other images that should not be cached. However, it seems like as soon as Picaso is running in any point in the app, then it starts caching all images no matter if I use Picaso loading on them or not.

**How can I not cache certain images using Picasso?**

** Does Picasso setups your app that any image loading is cached regardless of using Picasso or not?**

The method I use to download my images are:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Picasso to cache an image you can use .skipMemoryCache() like so:

```
Picasso.with(VenueDetailsActivity.this).load(url).skipMemoryCache().into(logo);
```

For more information you can view the documentation [here](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#skipMemoryCache--)

Comment: Like I said, I am not even using Picasso for the image that needs to not be cached. I am using the normal way of downloading an image. However, I even tried it with Picasso using the .skipMemoryCache() method but that didn't work also.